# OpenProcess/ReadProcessMemory/WriteProcessMemory/CloseHandle equivalent

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, unix

What would be the equivalent api to these Windows functions? In case you are not familiar with the windows functions, all they do is open a process, access(read and write) its memory and close its handle.

Can this be done with syscalls only as well?

Comment: There is a good page ***[HERE](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-MigratingWin32toLinux.html)*** discussing _Migrating Win32 C/C++ applications to Linux on POWER, Part 1: Process, thread, and shared memory services_

Comment: readprocessmemory, writeprocessmemory and closehandle similar to read, write and close operation on file descriptor in linux. and i didn't found any linux api to get fd from processid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [ptrace](http://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/08/14/ptrace-tutorial/). Despite the name, it will also target individual threads on Linux and possibly other systems. More info can be found with Google if that blog post doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a more modern kernel, you might try [process_vm_readv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/process_vm_readv.2.html) which seems to more closely simulate ReadProcessMemory, only it works slightly more cleanly than ptrace and even the Windows equivalents.